# Ошибка TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Вот код:

```
import openai

import telebot


openai.api_key = 'token'

bot = telebot.TeleBot("token")


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda _: True)

def handle_message(message):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        model="text-davinci-003",
        prompt="message.text",
        temperature=0.5,
        max_tokens=1000,
        top_p=1.0,
        frequency_penalty=0.5,
        presence_penalty=0.0,
    )

    print(response['choices'][0]['text'])

bot.polling()
```

Он выдаёт ошибку:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda _: True) AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'
```

Как это решить?

Comment: А как библиотеку устанавливали?

Comment: библиотека установлена в активированное виртуальное окружение? Лишняя пустая строка еще между декоратором и функцией.

Comment: pip install telebot

Comment: тут так загрузилось в коде она идёт сразу